# How do I (effectively) backstab bees?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I've been having a rough time killing bees with finesse. Given their small size and ability to fly, it seems nearly impossible to stab them in the back.

Since the Finesse rating is (at least partially) based on how many backstabs I pull off during an encounter, I typically get no higher than a B when I'm fighting bees.

At least once, I've somehow managed to get a supposed "backstab", but the bee was at least 20 feet above me and both myself and my party member that assisted me with the Blindside whiffed gloriously at nothing and did a whopping 0 damage, so I don't even think that counted.

Is there a good strategy for stabbing bees (or any other small, flying enemy, really) in the back?

Comment: beeeeeeeeeeeeees?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf yeah, should've titled this "NOT THE BEES"

Comment: I resorted to using warpstrikes or ranged weapons when i fought bees or flying enemies because it was MUCH easier. Getting backstabs...no clue.

Comment: @Mayshar, yeah that's how I've been handling them, but I'm struggling to get backstabs

Comment: As it stands this is not a good question title for this site.  This is clickbait-y at best, and doesn't actually portray the nature of the question.

Comment: @widuhmakeh, fair enough.

Comment: I've had moderate luck using the Star of the Rogue royal arm as it works at range, and still seems to trigger the boosted dmg.

Answer (score 1):

Go in to the options in the pause menu, then gameplay and change it from "Active" to "Wait Mode". When you are approaching enemy bees, target them with the lock on button and then use the right stick to select the area in which to strike them. Then warp strike then. Keep trying this over and over and obviously warp/ roll behind them if possible and lock on and select again.

Hope this helps!